# Why are the edges of our subfloor wet after rain, but the walls are completely dry?

Tags: water, floor, subfloor, rain, wet

Our house has a stucco exterior and a dirt crawlspace, part of the crawlspace is wet, but there isn't much water pooling down there. Where the water is pooling, the subfloor is completely dry.

The section of the subfloor that is wet, the area of the crawlspace beneath it is dry. Or the section of the floor doesn't have a crawlspace beneath it.

I added a picture of a part of the section that's wet, but basically, in that room, 2 edges of the subfloor are wet. Ignore the white paint (the previous owners put paint on the subfloor for some reason, we just got the house and peeled up the carpet and found it like that). Any ideas on what could be happening to make only the edges of our subfloor wet?

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us the wall layers? You mention stucco on the outside, but I’m assuming behind that you have a wire mesh, then an air barrier or drainage layer like building paper or house wrap, then wood sheeting, batt insulation, poly vapor barrier, and then finally drywall? If that’s not correct please say so. Also can you say what is above the room where the subfloor is wet? Is it the top story of the house, so there’s drywall ceiling, poly vapor barrier, insulation, rafters or trusses, sheathing, roofing paper, shingles?  Basically tell us the building envelope.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the wall layers are. I think there is definitely a wire mesh, (not sure about the building paper), definitely a vapor barrier and insulation, but I'm not sure if there is a wood sheeting. Above the subfloor is the top story of the house, so there is a drywall ceiling, insulation, vapor barrier, rafters (I think), and shingles roofing. It's a one a story house.

Comment: My guess is that you have water on the exterior facing side of the plastic vapor barrier and once it hits the bottom plate of the walls it’s being absorbed by the plywood subfloor.

Comment: either water is condensing behind the stucco or water is leaking through the wall, but theres's not enough information to guess which.

Comment: I'm surprised the surveyor didn't find & report that - you may have a case against them for missing it.